# Um «sim-senhor» é um par de nádegas?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, expressões

Encontrei isto por acaso no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), que diz que é um lusitanismo tabu. O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sim-senhor) diz só que é informal, e não restringe a Portugal.

Eu até já poderei perante alguns pares de nádegas ter exclamado para com os meus botões, *Sim-senhor!* Mas nunca ouvi designar as nádegas por *sim-senhor*, tipo, *Mas que belo sim-senhor!* ou coisas assim.

Onde é que isto se usa? Alguém tem conhecimento de tal uso de *sim-senhor*? E é tabu ou simplesmente informal?

Comment: Também nunca ouvi...

Comment: Eu também usaria "sim senhor" da mesma forma.  Ou, dependendo do que visse, poderia até usar um palavrão do tipo "pqp", como uma interjeição, mas no bom sentido de que estaria muito surpreso por nunca ter visto algo tão bonito.  Mas nunca ouvi ninguém chamar de "sim senhor" aquela parte da anatomia.

Comment: Em pt-BR usamos "nádegas", "bunda", "traseiro", "padaria", etc. etc.

Comment: Eu até aceitaria um "sim senhor" como "nádegas", se as tais forem dignas de um comentário muito elogioso.  Caso contrário, não cabe a expressão, na minha opinião.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O termo "Sim senhor" é aplicado (ou mais corretamente, era usado faz algum tempo mas tornou-se fora de moda) como referência ás nádegas do seguinte modo:

> Chega para lá o sim senhor.

Como forma de pedir a alguém (normalmente alguém conhecido e com quem se tem alguma confiança, e não um desconhecido) para mudar de lugar ou fazer espaço.

Um uso diferente para a expressão "Sim senhor" é também o uso como crítica a qualquer ação que não se aprova, usado como ironia:

> Sim senhor, que "lindo" serviço fizeste neste documento... ficou todo mal formatado!

Comment: Muito interessante. Onde é que ouves ou costumavas ouvir esse *chega para lá o sim-senhor*? Seria interessante incluir essa informação. Pode dar-se o caso de esse *sim-senhor* só se usar em certas regiões.

Comment: Nos anos 60 e 70 (quando eu era adoloscente) era um termo bastante em uso. seria um modo "educado" para referir ao traseiro. Sendo de Lisboa diria que era mais usada na zona centro e Alentejo mas nao era limitado a uma area geográfica mas sim a um nivel cultural onde referencia a partes anatomicas eram consideradas tabu e se usavam substitutos do genero. do mesmo modo se usava o termo "tintins" para referir a testiculos,

Comment: @Jacinto Gostei dessa pergunta porque me trouxe algumas memórias. Já me tinha caído totalmente no esquecimento, mas agora que leio isto recorda-me de o meu falecido avô utilizar essa expressão, geralmente em tom jocoso ou de brincadeira, e a minha tia também. Do género: "*Se não te portas bem levas umas palmadas no sim-senhor*" ou "*Fulano tal precisava de um pontapé no sim-senhor*" . Como referido nesta resposta penso que seja uma expressão arcaica que caiu em desuso nos dias que correm. Eu pelo menos acho que nunca mais a ouvi desde então.

Comment: @Duarte E tu ouvias isso em Lisboa também?

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, em Lisboa. O meu avô era de origem Algarvia, no entanto, e a minha tia nasceu e Angola em contextos bastante diferentes, por isso parece ser uma expressão que de certa forma se difundiu bastante

Comment: Eu também ouvia, no *Norte*, usado da mesma forma que o @DuarteFarrajotaRamos diz; talvez há 15-25 anos. Também não me lembro de o ouvir recentemente.

Comment: @ANeves, fosca-se, também tu! parece que só eu é que nunca tinha ouvido aquilo!